# If my instance is an array, how do i set values of it's array type variable

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class called Combination which has one array type variable. What I am trying to do is put x (predefined) number of objects into an array. What confuses me is that both my instance and it's variable are arrays. Do I need one dimensional array to place objects in it, or does it have to be two dimensional since my variable is an array?

```
public class Combination {
    public int[] combination = new int[6];

    public Combination(int[] combination) {
        super();
        this.combination = combination;
    }

    public Combination() {
        super();
    }
}

public class Glavna {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter number of combinations");
        int combNum = s.nextInt();
        Combination k = new Combination();
        Combination[] array1 = new Combination[combNum];  // which one of these 2 is correct
        Combination[][] array2 = new Combination[combNum][6];  // which one of these 2 is correct
        k.kombinacija[3] = 5;         // This works fine
        array1[0].combination = 1;      //  This throws NullPointerException
        array2[0][0].combination[0] = 1;    //  This throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

**Input**: 2 
 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12 
**Desired output**: 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 11 12

If output was called final[], then final[1] was first row and final[2] second row.

Thank you.

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to achieve, however from what I understood is your are trying to initialize an array. Couple of points, you are already defined the length of the array hence you need to initialize with the same size i.e. 6. Now either you take input exactly 6 items and just define and initialize an array and create you Combination object as.. int [ ] intArray = int {1,2,3,4,5,6}... Combination c = new Combination (intArray);

Comment: Combination[] array1 = new Combination[5];  you're allocating memory to your array but it still empty so you can't access its first element  (combination array)
you're trying to access combination property of a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this answer is help to you:

```
public class Glavna {
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter number of combinations");
    int combNum = s.nextInt();
    Combination k = new Combination();
    Combination combination1 = new Combination();  // Combination object 1
    Combination combination2 = new Combination();  // Combination object 2
    System.out.println("Enter inputs");
    for (int i = 0; i < combNum; i++) {
        if (i <= 5) {
            combination1.combination[i] = s.nextInt(); // Assign input set 1 to combination object 1 array
        } else {
            combination2.combination[i-6] = s.nextInt(); // Assign input set 2 to combination object 2 array
        }
    }

    //Print output separately
    System.out.println("Desired output: ");
    for (int l : combination1.combination) {
        System.out.print(l + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int l : combination2.combination) {
        System.out.print(l + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your help, i was able to understand what was wrong with my code and fixed it.Guess i made this question more complex that it was supposed to be.